# C++ undefined reference to ... and also warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to 'char*'

Tags: c++

in C++ i am getting these two errors

```
undefined reference to 'Employee::Employee'
warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to 'char*'
```

in the following two parts of my code. I know there are many topics about that but i can't solve it by my own.... What do I have to do to fix this?

1.

```
Employee::Employee(SymbolStr sstr, int* egn, int* cd)
{
    sbstr=sstr;
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        id[i] = egn[i];
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        code[i] = cd[i];
}
```

2.

```
int main()
{
    ofstream fileout("LuboHW.txt");
    cout << "Please, enter how many entries of employee's information would you like to make?" << endl;
    int count;
    cin >> count;
    //cin.ignore();
    Employee* emp = new Employee[count];
    for(int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        cout << "Entering information about employee number " << i << ": " << endl;
        emp[i].read();
    }
    cout << "Please, enter the code of the desired employee position: " << endl;
    int cd[4];
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        cin >> cd[i];
        //cin.ignore();
    //writing information about employee in fileout.txt, searching by code
    for(int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
        {
            if(*emp[j].getCode() == cd[i])
                continue;
            if(j == 3)
                fileout << emp[i] << endl;
        }
    }
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The first thing you can do is format your question so it's actually readable.

Comment: Please keep the rule "1 question = 1 question", okay?

Comment: thx for the help guys i now know the rules ^^

Comment: My conception is that your class lacks a default constructor because of the one you defined for it, and that `*emp[j].getCode()` is wrong.

Comment: The full errors are in the "output" window in Visual Studio.  The "error" window only has summaries.

Answer (score 4):

To call `new Employee[count]` you need an `Employee` default constructor (`Employee::Employee()`).

`Employee::Employee(SymbolStr sstr, int* egn, int* cd)` isn't  a default constructor.

Comment: The problem with this is in the main   Employee* emp = new Employee[count];

Comment: i kinda switched them accidently